# new to html and css - how do I modify grid positioning

Tags: html, css

I am building a site that has 3 colums,

```
.grid, .col-1-3, .col-2-3 {
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
 .container,
     .grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
 }
```

I find that the third column is flowing over to the next line -

I am trying to tweak the padding etc and not getting anywhere - help

nb totally new to html as of 1 week
 thanks

Comment: put more code here , your HTML code too

Comment: post the full code here

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to have a row with 3 columns, you need to have width of each column to be exactly (or less) 1/3 pixels  of total width.
So if container is 960px, your column needs to be 320px or less.

Otherwise,  I suggest to look into flex-box and css grid. This might help you and is probably a better solution to your problem.

Happy coding :)